# Warum haben Deutsche einen "Vogel", wenn sie ein wenig verrückt sind?

Tags: phrase, idiom, etymology

Woher kommt wohl die Redewendung

> *"Du hast ja einen Vogel!"* oder *"Der hat eine Meise!"*

die man hört, wenn jemand eine andere Person (oder deren Idee) für etwas verrückt hält?

Hängt auch *"jemand den den Vogel zeigen"* damit zusammen? Gibt es eine ähnliche Redewendung im Englischen oder in anderen Sprachen?

Comment: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jemandem_einen_Vogel_zeigen

Comment: @Hackworth den Vogel zeigen ist aber etwas anderes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Die Geolino-Site hat [folgende Erklärung:](http://www.geo.de/GEOlino/mensch/redewendungen/deutsch/5212.html), wie die Redensart entstanden ist.

> Das ist zwar eine seltsame Vorstellung, aber die Redewendung "der hat doch einen Vogel" wird oft benutzt, wenn Menschen etwas Dummes erzählt oder getan haben. Früher wurde dieser Ausspruch jedoch nur zu geisteskranken Menschen gesagt.
>
> Es war nämlich ein alter Volksglaube, dass Geistesgestörtheit von Vögeln ausgelöst wurde. Allerdings nicht dadurch, dass die Menschen Tauben züchteten oder Kanarienvögel und Wellensittiche besaßen. Nein, damals wurde angenommen, dass die Vögel direkt im Gehirn nisten sollten. Und wenn dann jemand etwas tat, was die anderen nicht nachvollziehen konnten, dann hatte der wohl einen Vogel - im Kopf.
>
> Genau so erklärt sich übrigens auch der Ausspruch "Bei dir piept es wohl"!

Comment: Pardon, aber plausibel ist das nicht. Weder hört man Geisteskranke piepen, noch etwas flattern, dann kam noch nie ein Vogel aus dem Kopf eines Menschen raus oder flog da rein. Genausogut könnte man annehmen, der Bekloppte habe einen Fisch im Kopf! Oder eine Basilikumpflanze. Oder wieso nicht ein Gewitter?

Answer (score 5):

Ich glaube, das nächste Äquivalent auf Englisch wäre das Adjektiv 'cuckoo' (Kuckuck).  'He's cuckoo' bedeutet, dass er etwas bekloppt ist.

Answer (score 1):

Nun ob es etymologisch korrekt ist, weiss ich nicht, aber stelle Dir folgendes Bild vor:

Ein enger Käfig, darin ein Vogel.
Der Käfig als Metapher für den Kopf eines Menschen.
Der Vogel flattert unruhig (="verrückt") darin herum.

Answer (score -1):

Der Ausspruch kommt aus der Falknerei. Falkner mussten im Mittelalter sehr zuverlässig sein und durften keinen Alkohol trinken. Da die Freizeitbeschäftigung seinerzeit nicht so ausgeprägt war, als heutzutage, ging man eben in die Wirtschaft und trank in seiner Freizeit. Wenn man nicht trank, dann war das sehr ungewöhnlich, das heißt mit dem Betreffenden konnte etwas nicht stimmen. Entschuldigte sich der betreffende Falkner jedoch mit dem Satz: "Ich hab einen Vogel, dann war klar, dass er zwar normal war, aber von seiner beruflichen Stellung her nicht trinken durfte.

Comment: Sehr hübsch, aber mE nicht sonderlich plausibel. Quelle?