# Über den Ursprung der zu „einen Vogel haben“ zugeordneten Geste

Tags: etymology, idiom

Anstelle folgender Aussagen:

> *Du hast einen Vogel*, *bei dir piept es wohl*, usw.

macht man manchmal eine Geste. 
Ich erkenne nur folgende Zeichen.

1. Zeigefinger zur Stirn, genau wo die Schläfe anfängt. Ein paar Mal langsam mit dem Zeigefingerkuppe die Stirn berühren.
2. Die gut 10 cm-entfernte Hand vor dem Gesicht, Handteller zum Gesicht gerichtet, „schnell“ bewegen.

Welchen Ursprung und welche „Etymologie“ hat diese Geste?

---

[Diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2667/warum-haben-deutsche-einen-vogel-wenn-sie-ein-wenig-verruckt-sind) und dieser [Wikipedia-Artikel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einen_Vogel_haben) stehen auch in Zusammengang mit dieser Frage.

Comment: Sind die Gesten nicht international?

Comment: @userunknown Eigentlich nicht. Die mit dem Zeigenfinger  bedeutet "du bist Klug" in einigen Ländern.

Comment: @userunknown http://www.ikkompetenz.thueringen.de/selbsttest/offenheit/

Comment: Der Link beantwortet meine Frage nicht. Die Frage ist, ob die Gesten spezifisch für den dt. Sprachraum sind.

Comment: @userunknown Die Antwort auf deine Frage ist schlicht *Nein*, auch wenn es einige Gesten gibt, die überall gleich verstanden werden.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es gibt einen besseren Artikel auf Wikipedia darüber: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einen_Vogel_zeigen

In Absatz 2 and 3 steht auch etwas zur Etymologie. Anscheinend zeigt man mit der Geste auf einen imaginären Vogel, der sich im Kopf des Gegenübers eingenistet hat.

Die zweite Geste kenne ich als "Scheibenwischer", und sie rührt vermutlich daher, dass man sein Gegenüber auf einen vernebelten Geist oder ein vernebeltes Sichtfeld hinweisen will, welches dieser zu "säubern" habe. Das ist allerdings nur eine Vermutung von mir, im Wörterbuch habe ich dazu nichts gefunden.

Answer (score -2):

Die Antwort von Martin Hansen hat mich auf die Idee gebracht hat, dass diese Geste eng mit dem bekannten "Spatzenhirn" verwandt sein könnte. Der Spatz, auf den man dann mit dem Finger zeigt..

Comment: Und? Hast du dann mal recherchiert? Was war das Ergebnis?